# batch choice command will not work

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-choice

I have this question about why this choice command won't work. I've looked on this site and compared all my scripting and I just can't figure out why it won't work
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001674.htm

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
echo 1 to quit or 2 to print hello and go back to this screen
CHOICE /C:12 /N
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO QUIT
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO HELLO
GOTO :START
:QUIT
EXIT
:HELLO 
ECHO hello
GOTO :END
:END
```

Comment: Use %ERRORLEVEL% instead of ERRORLEVEL

Comment: Yeah was my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes and removed unnecessary code.

```bat
@ECHO OFF

:START
CLS
ECHO=1 to quit or 2 to print hello and go back to this screen
CHOICE /C 12 /N
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (CALL :HELLO & GOTO START)
EXIT /B

:HELLO 
ECHO=hello
TIMEOUT 2 1>NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing on the `errorlevel` is done wrong.

There are two possibilities:

```
@ECHO OFF

:BEGIN
ECHO 1 to quit or 2 to print hello and go back to this screen
CHOICE /C:12 /N
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO HELLO
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 EXIT /B
GOTO BEGIN

:HELLO
ECHO hello
GOTO BEGIN
```

For full details see the chapter about **CHOICE** in my answer on: [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

The batch user must press either <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> as otherwise the batch execution is not continued. So testing for the exit code can be done from highest to lowest with:

```
if errorlevel X ...
```

That means **IF** the exit code assigned to the *dynamic* variable `errorlevel` is **greater OR equal** X **THEN** execute the command (or command block).

The advantage of using this syntax is that it even works in a command block without the need to use delayed variable expansion.

The second possibility is:

```
@ECHO OFF

:BEGIN
ECHO 1 to quit or 2 to print hello and go back to this screen
CHOICE /C:12 /N
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 EXIT /B
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 GOTO HELLO
GOTO BEGIN

:HELLO
ECHO hello
GOTO BEGIN
```

By explicitly referencing the dynamic variable `ERRORLEVEL`, here with expansion before **IF** evaluates the condition, the order of the `errorlevel` checks does not matter anymore.

The disadvantage of this method is the need of using delayed expansion if **CHOICE** and the `errorlevel` evaluating conditions are within a command block defined with `(` ... `)`.

Run in a command prompt window `if /?` and `set /?` for help about right usage of the commands **IF** and **SET** respectively get information about delayed variable expansion.

It is possible to use `START` as label, but it is not advisable to do so because of **START** is an internal command of Windows command processor. You get troubles on finding `START` meaning the label and `START` meaning the command when your batch file will use ever also the command **START**. `BEGIN` is used as label for that reason.

It is also advisable to use command **EXIT** always with parameter `/B` at least during developing a batch file to exit only the batch processing, but do not completely exit the running command process independent on calling hierarchy and option used on starting `cmd.exe`.

It is much easier to debug a batch file by running it from within a command prompt window (`cmd.exe` started with option `/K` to keep console window open) instead of double clicking on the batch file (`cmd.exe` started with option `/C` to close on batch execution finished) on using `exit /B` instead of just `exit` as the command prompt window keeps open. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` for details about the options of the Windows Command Processor.

`GOTO BEGIN` after the two `errorlevel` evaluations is only executed on user pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Break</kbd> on this prompt and presses on prompt output by `cmd` to terminate the batch job the key <kbd>N</kbd>. That results in an exit of **CHOICE** with exit code 0.

It would be better to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe` instead of just `CHOICE` if the batch file is for Windows Vista or Windows Server 2003 or newer Windows versions with support of [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **CHOICE**.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
@ECHO OFF
:START
echo 1 to quit or 2 to print hello and go back to this screen
CHOICE /C 12 /N
GOTO OPTION-%ERRORLEVEL%

:OPTION-1  Quit
EXIT

:OPTION-2  Hello
ECHO hello
GOTO START
```